# Inserting Multiple values from a single form Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello all i am trying to insert multiple records into the table using the same form so far i have achieved the following

```
class ProjectController < ApplicationController
def new
    @project = Project.new
end
def create

    @projec = Project.new(project_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html {  flash[:notice] = 'User successfully created.' and redirect_to action: "index"}

        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end    
    end
  end
def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:PROJECT_ID,:COMPANY_ID, :ASSESSMENT_ID, :PROJECT_SCORE , :CREATED_BY, :UPDATED_BY)
    end
end
```

so in my view i have used like this since i want only the project level score to be saved into the database with all other values remaining the same

```
<% 10.times do %>
    <%= f.range_field :PROJECT_SCORE[], :min=>0, :max=>10, :class=>"slide", :id=>"slider1", name: 'PROJECT_SCORE[of_values][]'%>
        <% end %>
```

next in my model i have used like this

```
class Project< ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :PROJECT_SCORE ,Array
end
```

but i receive an error

```
Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a Fixnum. -- 0
```

SO is there any alternate ways to insert multiple records in the table at the same time ? or how do i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternate way for inserting multiple records and I would highly recommend doing so.  You could get this to work but it feels a bit hacky and not very flexible to me.  Try using a **has_many** association and **nested forms** instead. If you're not familiar with has_many associations there is an introductory course at codeschool.com called *[Models Taste Like Chicken](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/rails-for-zombies-redux)*. There is also a great *[RailsCasts episode (#196)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)* that goes into detail about nested forms with some cool AJAX features.

To do this you could create a Model called Score and tell it to belong the projects:

`rails g model Score score:integer project:references`

```
class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

And each project will have many scores:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scores, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :scores, allow_destroy: true
end
```

The dependent destroy makes sure the associated scores get deleted if a Project is deleted. You also need to tell it to accept nested attributes for the scores model.  Details *[here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)*.

Next, set up the strong parameters with `things_attributes:[:thing1, :thing2, :etc]`

```
class ProjectController < ApplicationController

### other stuff

def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:PROJECT_ID, :etc, scores_attributes: [:id, :score])
end
```

> One thing I would like to mention here is the best practice for 
>   naming conventions is to use snake_case for your
>   variables and database names. So instead of `:PROJECT_ID` name it
>   `:project_id`
>   ALL_CAPS is usually used for constants.

Now your view you can use the `fields_for` form helper to create another form block within the form block.

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <!-- all normal form inputs -->
  </div>

  <!-- and now the nested form -->
  <%= f.fields_for :scores do |ff| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= ff.range_field :score %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This won't allow you to create new scores yet, but that starts to get really complicated and is explained in the RailsCasts I mentioned above (However he is using an older version of rails so make sure and set the strong parameters for the nested attributes).